# How do file permissions work on OpenShift?

Tags: php, cgi, openshift, file-permissions

I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about file permissions in an OpenShift PHP app.  How do they actually work?

I develop on OSX and push changes using SourceTree.  When I log in to the app via an SFTP program (Cyberduck) the index.php file shows its permissions set to 600, yet visitors can view it OK in a browser.

This surprises me, as I thought the file would require permissions of 644 to be browsable (like an Apache webserver).

On OpenShift, it seems as though file permissions 600, 640 and 644 are all equivalent.  Is this correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Related:
My OpenShift app has a cgi-bin folder containing a cgi program that should only be executed (called) from a PHP file.  In other words, any PHP script should be able to call this cgi program, but a visitor attempting to browse to the cgi-bin folder directly should not.

I set both the cgi-bin folder and cgi program file permissions to 700 (so only the 'owner' has read/write/execute set, and no permissions are granted for 'group' and 'others').  However visitors can still browse to the program URL directly and execute it (e.g. www.example.com/cgi-bin/program.cgi) - as if the permissions were 777.  How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are used to a system where one user owns the files being served, and the web server runs as another user, but since the files owner (your user account that is that big long hash) is also the owner of the process that runs the web server on OpenShift, then it is using the "6" part of the permissions, so it makes sense that the other two digits that you add don't make a difference.  If there is a script that you don't want web accessible, but that you want PHP to be able to execute, then you should place it outside of your web directory that contains your php files.  The easiest way to do that would be to create a "php" folder in your repo, and put your files inside of it that need to be web accessible.  That will change your documentRoot to that php directory, and you can put your script one level above that so users can't execute it with a web request.

Comment: Perfect.  That's a very clear explanation and solution.  Thank you.